# Как перевести поток из двоичного в обычный

Tags: c++

Есть файл который нужно записать сначала в двоичном режиме а потом нужно продолжить запись с того же места но уже в обычном режиме.

Comment: Только переоткрывать заново и дозаписывать в конец.

Comment: @user7860670 но тогда придется вводить дополнительную переменную которая будет хранить имя файла.

Comment: очень даже может быть

Comment: А зачем вам это? Любые данные можно записать в двоичном режиме.

Comment: Ну напишите `f.write(&c,sizeof(c)); f << c;` :) - в чем проблема?

Comment: А в чем проблема? В linux, например, любой файл априори открывается в двоичном режиме...

Comment: в линуксе проблем нет. в винде нужно просто перевод строки записывать как два байта. Это все, что делает текстовый режим (ну почти все).

Comment: @KoVadim Это необязательно, винда поймет и один `\n`.